# Have trouble diplaying tax owed of people in a text file depending on their income and filing status

Tags: c#

I cannot figure out how to do this tax owed calculation inside of the text file I'm using.  When I run the program, it displays the income and filing status of every person, but the tax owed doesn't show up.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Customers.CustomerTax(DataIO.TextFileToString(@"C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\tax.txt"));

        foreach (Customers item in Customers._taxList)

        {

            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());

            FilingStatus fs = (FilingStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(FilingStatus), "Single");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where I do my calculations

```
class Customers
{

    String _marriage;
    double _income;
    double _taxOwed;
    private FilingStatus _filingstatus;

    public static List<Customers> _taxList = new List<Customers>();



    public Customers(String marriage, int income)
    {
        Income = income;
        Marriage = marriage;

    }

    public String Marriage
    {
        get { return _marriage; }
        set
        {

            _marriage = value;

        }
    }



    public double Income
    {
        get { return _income; }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("{0} must be > 0", value));
            }
            _income = value;

        }
    }

    public double CalculateTax()
    {
        double taxOwed = 0.0;

        if (_filingstatus == FilingStatus.Single)
        {
            if (Income <= TaxCalculations.Single10)
            {
                taxOwed = .1 * Income;
            }

            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.Single15)
            {
                taxOwed = .15 * Income;
            }
            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.Single25)
            {
                taxOwed = .25 * Income;
            }
            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.Single28)
            {
                taxOwed = .28 * Income;
            }
            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.Single33)
            {
                taxOwed = .33 * Income;
            }
            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.Single35)
            {
                taxOwed = .35 * Income;
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Derp");
        }
        else if (_filingstatus == FilingStatus.MarriedJoint)
        {
            if (Income <= TaxCalculations.MarriedJoint10)
            {
                taxOwed = .1 * Income;
            }

            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.MarriedJoint15)
            {
                taxOwed = .15 * Income;
            }
            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.MarriedJoint25)
            {
                taxOwed = .25 * Income;
            }

            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.MarriedJoint28)
            {
                taxOwed = .28 * Income;
            }
            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.MarriedJoint33)
            {
                taxOwed = .33 * Income;
            }

            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.MarriedJoint35)
            {
                taxOwed = .35 * Income;
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Derp");
        }
        else if (_filingstatus == FilingStatus.MarriedSeparate)
        {
            if (Income <= TaxCalculations.MarriedSeparate10)
            {
                taxOwed = .1 * Income;
            }

            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.MarriedSeparate15)
            {
                taxOwed = .15 * Income;
            }
            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.MarriedSeparate25)
            {
                taxOwed = .25 * Income;
            }

            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.MarriedSeparate28)
            {
                taxOwed = .28 * Income;
            }
            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.MarriedSeparate33)
            {
                taxOwed = .33 * Income;
            }

            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.MarriedSeparate35)
            {
                taxOwed = .35 * Income;
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Derp");
        }
        else if (_filingstatus == FilingStatus.HeadOfHouse)
        {
            if (Income <= TaxCalculations.HeadOfHouse10)
            {
                taxOwed = .1 * Income;
            }

            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.HeadOfHouse15)
            {
                taxOwed = .15 * Income;
            }
            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.HeadOfHouse25)
            {
                taxOwed = .25 * Income;
            }

            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.HeadOfHouse28)
            {
                taxOwed = .28 * Income;
            }
            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.HeadOfHouse33)
            {
                taxOwed = .33 * Income;
            }

            else if (Income <= TaxCalculations.HeadOfHouse35)
            {
                taxOwed = .35 * Income;
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Derp");

        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Not a Valid Filing Status");
        return taxOwed;

    }       


    public static void CustomerTax(String s)
    {

        String[] customersArr = s.Split('\n');

        foreach (string item in customersArr)
        {
            if (item.Equals("")) continue;

            String[] customer = item.Split(',');
            Customers p = new Customers(customer[1], int.Parse(customer[0]));
            _taxList.Add(p);


        }
    }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Income: {0} Marriage Status: {1} Tax Owed: {2}", _income, _marriage, _taxOwed);

        }
    }
}
```

StreamReader, Data IO

```
class DataIO
{
    public static String TextFileToString(String path)
    {
        String output = "";
        String record = "";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {

            while ((record = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                output += record + "\n";
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got a lot of extra `}` in your code. You might want to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's a problem with your ToString function?

```
public override string ToString()
{
     return String.Format("Income: {0} Marriage Status: {1} Tax Owed:", _income, _marriage, _taxOwed);
}
```

Should be something like the following:
Add your braces for the third argument in the Format String?

```
public override string ToString()
{
     return String.Format("Income: {0} Marriage Status: {1} Tax Owed: {2}", _income, _marriage, _taxOwed);
}
```

Comment: I fixed these errors, but the tax owed shows up as 0 for every person in my text file.

Comment: I was a bit confused myself about it at first, but you aren't even setting the `_taxOwed` variable anywhere in your code.  That's probably your next problem to resolve.

Comment: And then your next problem is going to be that you haven't set your `_filingstatus` anywhere in your code.  So because it's not set, your `taxOwed` variable is still not going to be set.  These are fairly basic principles that you're missing.  A tutor or a class would probably be a better place to go to gain a better understanding of what you're doing.  Of course, I, myself, have not really programmed in C#, so I could be missing something, too.